# How to optimize this LINQ expression w/ Where condition and calling Method?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am seeking any advice or tips on the following method I have that is using LINQ to find a certain property in a Collection that is null and then go through the results (sub-list) and execute a method on another property from the same Collection.

```
private void SetRaises()
{
    if (employeeCollection != null)
    {
      var noRaiseList = employeeCollection .Where(emp => emp.Raise == null).ToList();
      foreach (var record in noRaiseList )
      {
         CalculateRaise(record);
      }
    }
}

public void CalculateRaise(Employee emp)
{
    if (emp!= null)
        emp.Raise = emp.YearsOfService * 100;
}
```

The part I don't like in the first method, SetRaises(), is the following snippet:

```
foreach (var record in noRaiseList )
{
    CalculateRaise(record);
}
```

Is there a way to integrate that part into my LINQ expression directly, i.e. some extension method I am not aware of?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you show `CalculateQd` when you use `CalculateRaise`?

Comment: There's no need to call `.ToList()`.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968791/how-to-perform-an-update-using-linq-or-lambdac-asp-net-linq-lambda

Comment: Tim, thanks for the reply and it was fault on copying the wrong text and have since updated my original text, thanks.

Comment: Thanks PLB for the tip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you could do would be: *don't generate an intermediate list*:

```
 var pending = employeeCollection.Where(emp => emp.Raise == null);
 foreach (var record in pending)
 {
     CalculateRaise(record);
 }
```

which is identical to:

```
 foreach (var record in employeeCollection.Where(emp => emp.Raise == null))
 {
     CalculateRaise(record);
 }
```

This is now non-buffered deferred execution.

But frankly, the LINQ here isn't giving you much. You could also just:

```
foreach(var emp in employeeCollection)
{
    if(emp.Raise == null) CalculateRaise(emp);
}
```

Comment: Can we not do it in one line? Just asking.

Comment: @guarav of course - I was just trying to keep it consistent. However, I'm not sure why everyone always seems obsessed with "do everything on one line". That is not the thing to aim for in code.

Comment: I'm guilty of that sometimes.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Marc Gravell for all the helpful tips and I also appreciate you commenting on others' answers as well.  Greatly appreciate the explanations!!

Comment: Just wondering, is there "any" performance difference between the last two solutions, i.e. one with LINQ (.Where) and the one w/o using LINQ and simply a foreach loop?

Comment: @user118190 there will be an extra layer of indirection via LINQ and the "where" iterator, but frankly you would not actually notice any performance difference in real world code for that.

Comment: @MarcGravell - Thanks again! You should write BOOKS! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need list of employees without Raise you can do this in one line:

```
employeeCollection.Where(emp => emp.Raise == null).ToList().ForEach(x => x.Raise = x.YearsOfService * 100);
```

Comment: that is horrible on so many levels. Unclear; hard to read; inefficient (intermediate lists; multiple iterations of the data). Basically, I would struggle to come up with an uglier implementation, unless I introduced `DataTable` into the middle for no particular reason.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ForEach chain-method. But that's only sugar syntax.

```
employeeCollection.Where(emp => emp.Raise == null)
                  .ToList()
                  .ForEach(record => CalculateRaise(record))
```

Comment: see my comment on gzaxx's post; everything I said there applies here too

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
var noRaiseList = employeeCollection .Where(emp => emp.Raise == null).ToList().ForEach(e=>e.Raise = e.YearsOfService * 100);
```

Comment: please see my comment on gzaxx's post; everything I said there applies here too